# Is “how the end result turns out” redundant?

Tags: redundancy, resultative

Is “how the end result turns out” wrong?

I’m talking about venting my feelings on the art I am currently doing. I would like to construct a sentence which is like depending my fortune on the outcome of it. Now, I wonder if “end result” makes “turns out” redundant. Here is my full sentence:

> “How the end result turns out will tell what I truly feel.”

Comment: I think this is more of a style question than an English question.  [Clearly people do use the phrase "end result turns out"](https://www.google.com/search?q="end+result+turns+out") but in the opinion of this US English speaker it's clumsy and inelegant, because the end result doesn't turn out, the end result *is* how something else turns out.

Comment: Thank you, @stangdon! What do you think is the appropriate wording for what I wanted to say?

Comment: @ArrowCase: You're switching the "causal agent" in OP's original, ***and*** changing the nature of what it's claimed that agent will do. In yours, what the speaker feels will be *determined* by the result, but in OP's original we assume the speaker's feelings are already "fixed" - what the result will do is *tell others* what the speaker feels.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see, I missed that interpretation. I read "venting my feelings on the art I am currently doing" to mean "expressing my feelings about the process of creating this art so far." To clarify, OP might have said they are venting their feelings *through* the art they are currently doing.

Comment: @ArrowCase: Of course, I'm only basing my observation on the specific word ***tell*** in OP's text, and since s/he's not a native speaker, it's quite possible that's a mistake, and it should have been ***determine*** or similar.

Comment: @arrowcase  it’s like I’m sign seeking. And yes, “determine” could’ve made it easier to understand.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it’s like depending the discernment of my most dominant feeling on the end result of what I’m doing. For example, I am cooking, and I am currently having mixed emotions. Cooking is where I’m venting my feelings into. If the end result is bitter, then maybe I’m feeling bitter but if it turns out good and delicious, then maybe I am happy. Actually I was just asking if “end result” makes “turns out” redundant, but it turns out there is more grammatical/wording error in my sentence.

Comment: Roma A: @stangdon''s first comment covers most of what's involved here (it's clumsy phrasing; we don't like it), but there are subtle reasons why a Google search for **end result turns out** might make you think your example is more "acceptable" than it really is. For example *The end result **turned out** to be totally unexpected* is relatively "okay" because that result might *turn out = prove* to meet the description *much later* than when the result actually occurred. But in your case, ***how*** it turned out would normally be understood as happening *at or before* the time of the result.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you for taking time to explain all these things. It means a lot especially to a non-native speaker like me.

Answer (score -1):

In this sentence the writer eagerly waits for the final outcome ( perhaps how his artwork is acclaimed), and that response from others has the final say on the creator's mood, dejected or elated. The  work would perhaps bring him name, fame and fortune. As to its construction, it is nonetheless syntactic, but poorly worded.

What turns out of something, is the end result. It would be better if we leave " turns out". But if we consider this from another perspective, "turns out" may be justified in the sentence in the sense the outcome may be for the good or worse. But we're squeamish about the clause, "what I truly feel" where the intended sense is something else : " what it means for me". You see, my feeling about my creation is essentially subjective and anything  exterior to me can ever change that.

So "turns out" is not redundant better let's try to express effectively in the 'what-clause' that follws it.